# Is there a capture event for NgTable for Column Reorder

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, angular-datatables

Is there a ngTableEventsChannel for ColReorder, basically i need to know if There was a Column ReOrder done on my DataTable in an Angular app using ng-table

Comment: Which ng-table library are you using?

Comment: am using angular-ng-table.min.js